# How do you use java-stream to compare two files and find the sum of values in a certain grouping?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Basically, I have two files: counties.txt and people.txt.

Each line in the counties file has

- County
- State
- ZipCode

and each line in the people file has

- FirstName
- LastName
- Income
- ZipCode.

What I need to do is calculate the average income for each county using the people.txt file using streams and lambdas in Java 8.

I've created two classes that store all the relevant information and have getter and setter methods
County Class: String county, String state_abbrev, long zipcode, and int averageIncome
Person Class: String firstName, String lastName, int income, long zipcode, String county

Once I've found the average income, I want to compare each person's income to the average in their respective county. Here's what I've tried, and it works if there is only one zipcode in a county, but otherwise, it's filtering the zipcodes separately instead of combining them for each county

```
       //filter the people based on zip code , find the average county income and set it in county object
   counties.forEach(county -> {
       int sum = persons.stream().filter(p -> p.getZipcode() == county.getZipcode()).mapToInt(p -> p.getIncome()).sum();
       int count = (int)persons.stream().filter(p -> p.getZipcode() == county.getZipcode()).count();
       county.setAverageIncome(sum/count);
   });

   //filter the people based on zip code , set updated income
   counties.forEach(county -> {
       List<Person> person = persons.stream().filter(p -> p.getZipcode() == county.getZipcode()).collect(Collectors.toList());
       persons.removeAll(person);
       person.forEach(per -> {
           per.setIncome(per.getIncome() - county.getAverageIncome());
           per.setCounty(county.getCounty());
           persons.add(per);
       });

   });
```

I'm fairly certain the error is with finding the average county income, but it's possible it could be with updating the compared income.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said that 1 county can have multiple zip codes. I think that your code does not take that into account. Your counties list may contain multiple entries with the same `county`, but different `zipCode`. That's why you average the income by zipCode, and not by county.

```
Map<Long, String> zipToCounty = counties.stream()
                                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(County::getZipCode, County::getCounty));

Map<String, List<Person>> peopleInCounty = persons.stream()
                                                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> zipToCounty.get(p.getZipCode())));

Map<String, Double> averagePerCounty = peopleInCounty.entrySet()
                                                     .stream()
                                                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(),
                                                                               e -> e.getValue()
                                                                                     .stream()
                                                                                     .mapToInt(Person::getIncome)
                                                                                     .average()
                                                                                     .orElse(0)));
```

In this sample,

- I first map each zip code to its county to have a quick possibility
- to group the people together by county.
- Then I average the persons' incomes per county.

Now you have, per county, the average income and the people living in it. It should then be easy to go through the persons and calculate the difference between their income and the county average.

---

**Edit**

In order to further process your data, you should rewrite your data type for counties. Right now, the class you have does still not reflect a real county (which can have multiple zip codes), but only an entry of the file (with exactly one zip). Furthermore, in your original approach, you replaced the person's actual income with the difference to the county average. The difference should be another attribute, as the two thing do not mean the same. Whether the county average and the difference to the personal income should be stored in the county and person objects at all (i.e. whether they really belong there) is a whole other topic.

Generally, keep in mind that classes should mirror your real-world objects. So, long story short, these are the data types we need (getters and setter omitted for readability):

```
public static class Person
{
    private Integer income;
    private Long    zipCode;  // not the county, as the person file does not contain it
    private String  firstname, lastname;

    private Integer aboveAverage;
}

public static class RawCounty
{
    private Long   zipCode;
    private String county;
    private String state;
}

public static class County
{
    private Set<Long> zipCodes;
    private String    county;
    private String    state;

    private Double    average;
}
```

Next, we will change the algorithm from before to this:

```
Collection<County> counties = rawCounties.stream()
                                         .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(RawCounty::getCounty,
                                                                        Collectors.mapping(raw -> {
                                                                            County county = new County();
                                                                            county.setState(raw.getState());
                                                                            county.setCounty(raw.getCounty());
                                                                            county.setZipCodes(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(raw.getZipCode())));
                                                                            return county;
                                                                        }, Collectors.reducing((c1, c2) -> {
                                                                            c1.getZipCodes()
                                                                              .addAll(c2.getZipCodes());
                                                                            return c1;
                                                                        }))))
                                         .values()
                                         .stream()
                                         .map(Optional::get)
                                         .collect(Collectors.toSet());

Map<Long, County> zipToCounty = new HashMap<>();
counties.forEach(c -> c.getZipCodes().forEach(z -> zipToCounty.put(z, c)));

Map<String, List<Person>> peopleInCounty = persons.stream()
                                                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> zipToCounty.get(p.getZipCode())
                                                                                                 .getCounty()));

counties.forEach(c -> c.setAverage(peopleInCounty.get(c.getCounty())
                                                 .stream()
                                                 .mapToInt(Person::getIncome)
                                                 .average()
                                                 .orElse(0)));

counties.forEach(c -> peopleInCounty.get(c.getCounty())
                                    .forEach(p -> p.setAboveAverage(p.getIncome() - c.getAverage())));
```

So, what do we do here?

1. We group all county file entries (`RawCounty`) by `county`, create `County` objects for them and merge those together.
2. In order to make finding a county for a zip code easier in step 3, we now map every zip code to the county it belongs to.
3. Is the same as before: group all persons by county.
4. For each county, get the residents, calculate their average income, and set it as the `average` value for the country.
5. Go over the counties and people again, read the county average that is now available and calculate the difference between it and the personal income.

Now the elements in your lists `counties` and `persons` should be nicely initialized.

Comment: How would I then iterate through the map to set the average of each county equal to what was calculated?

Comment: @Natalie I have added some more example code and explanation. Take your time and read some javadoc of the stream methods, especially in the first step.